# org.hibernate.MappingException Unable to find column with logical name annotation getter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, annotations

I have many classes where annotations placed above getter like this:

```
private Location location;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "LocationId", nullable = false)
public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}
```

That code worked with hibernate \ dto architecture, but i'm trying to implement Spring Data and i didn't do any changes in code, i just added spring-data in dependencies and i start getting error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name locationid in table LocationProperty
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.getPhysicalColumnName(Configuration.java:2949)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.IndexOrUniqueKeySecondPass.addConstraintToColumn(IndexOrUniqueKeySecondPass.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.IndexOrUniqueKeySecondPass.doSecondPass(IndexOrUniqueKeySecondPass.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1741)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1792)
```

It could be fixed by moving annotations from getter to field declaration, so this code is working:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "LocationId", nullable = false)
private Location location;


public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}
```

Spring-data is 1.3.0.RELEASE, i know it's very old BUT in this project we are using old hibernate, so i can't add newer, because i got huge amount of another errors with session factory etc. So this isn't an option.

Hibernate is 4.1.12.final

I can fix this by moving annotations, but there are hundreds of classes, so it's really dummy job.

Comment: This error is telling you that there is no column on the LocationProperty table called locationid.

Comment: @sovannarithcheav really? and why the code above works? (tip: bc there are such column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, JPA access the values of entity properties and map those to database columns using the entity’s property getter and setter methods.

You can put these property annotations on either the private properties or the public getter methods.

If you use AccessType.PROPERTY (default) and annotate the private properties instead of the JavaBean getters, the field names must match the property names. However, the names do not have to match if you annotate the JavaBean getters.

If you use AccessType.FIELD and annotate the getters instead of the properties, the field names must also match the JavaBean property names. In this case, they do not have to match if you annotate the properties.

You can change this using `@javax.persistence.Access` annotation

You can refer [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/access.html)

Comment: Thank you, that is an answer